# Function that get 3 word for strings, than combine them to 1 string and finally print the string in reverse

Tags: c, strings

I'm learning C and I got a task to make 3 function.

The first get 3 addresses of string, get 3 words from the user, and enter into the addresses.
The second get the 3 addresses of string and combine them to a new large string.
The last should get the new address and print in reverse the string.

I wrote this and will happy to hear of problems or things to improve.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 10

void swap(char *x, char *y) {
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void initWords(char* w1, char* w2, char* w3) {
    printf("Please enter a word\n");
    scanf("%s", w1);
    printf("Please enter another word\n");
    scanf("%s", w2);
    printf("Please enter one last word\n");
    scanf("%9s", w3);
}

char* concatWords(char* w1, char* w2, char* w3) {
    char* new_w = malloc(strlen(w1)+strlen(w2)+strlen(w3));
    strcat(new_w, w1);
    strcat(new_w, w2);
    strcat(new_w, w3);
    return new_w;
    free(new_w);
}

void printReversedWord(char* word) {
    int i;
    int number = strlen(word);
    for (i=0; i<=(number/2); i++) {
        swap(&word[i], &word[number-1-i]);
    }
    printf("%s", word);
}


int main() {
    char w1 [N + 1];
    char w2 [N + 1];
    char w3 [N + 1];
    initWords(w1, w2, w3);
    char* new_w = concatWords(w1, w2, w3);
    printReversedWord(new_w);
    
    return 0;
}
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `free(new_w)` has no effect. It is unreachable. And unnecessary (and dangerous if placed before `return`).
- `malloc(strlen(w1)+strlen(w2)+strlen(w3))` allocates one character less than necessary. There is no room for a zero terminator.
- `scanf`s make the code prone to the buffer overflow. Prefer `fgets`.
- I understand it is not a part of assignment, but think of separation of responsibilities. A function that just reverses the word is better than a function which reverses *and* prints it.
- `number` is not the greatest name. `new_word_length` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

**Bug**

`strcat(s1, s2)` requires that `s1` point to a *string*.  `new_w` does not point to a *string* as it lacks a certain *null character*.

```
char* new_w = malloc(strlen(w1)+strlen(w2)+strlen(w3));
strcat(new_w, w1);  // Bad
```

Better as

```
char* new_w = malloc(strlen(w1)+strlen(w2)+strlen(w3) + 1);
strcpy(new_w, w1);
```

**Avoid [Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm)**

Instead, retain the length of the strings and copy with that information.  Use `size_t` for string lengths.  Test for allocation success.

```
char* concatWords(const char* w1, const char* w2, const char* w3) {
  size_t l1 = strlen(w1);
  size_t l2 = strlen(w2);
  size_t l3 = strlen(w3);
  char* new_w = malloc(l1 + l2 + l3 + 1);  // +1 for the null character.
  if (new_w) {
    strcpy(new_w, w1);
    strcpy(new_w + l1, w2);
    strcpy(new_w + l1 + l2, w3);
    // or 
    memcpy(new_w, w1, l1);
    memcpy(new_w + l1, w2, l2);
    memcpy(new_w + l1 + l2, w3, l3 + 1);
  }
  return new_w;
}
```

**Poor code**

Quality code never uses `"%s"` without a width limit as in `scanf("%s",.. );`. It is worse than [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359).

Advanced solution.

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)

scanf("%" TOSTRING(N) "s", w1);
```

... or use `fgets()` and [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2410359).

Also check return value of `scanf()`.

**Side effect**

Goal is "print in reverse the string.", but instead code *reverses the string* and then prints. This leaves the string reversed as a side-effect.  Instead, simply print the string in reverse without changing the string.

```
void printReversedWord(const char* word) {
  size_t len = strlen(word);
  while (len > 0) {
    printf("%c", word[--len]); // or research putchar()
  }
}
```